# Use batch file to copy non-directory files to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to copy the contents of a folder to another directory, but inside the main directory is another series of folders and I only want to copy the non-folder items to the directory - how would I go about achieving this with a batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `xcopy` command, by default it will skip folders. You would have to use the `/S` or `/E` argument to force it to copy directories.

So the basic syntax is `xcopy source destination`

On the command line, use `xcopy /?` for a list of command line arguments you can use.

Comment: Thanks for that - new to using batch files and I had no idea it skipped folders. Appreciate it.